# How to express beginning and end of line in sed

Tags: sed, files, regular-expression, search, replace

I want to use sed to replace every `'}` that comes at the end of the line to `"}`. I wrote:

```
sed -i -e "s/'}$/\"}$/g"
```

But this replaces it to: `"}$`. What is wrong? How can I use regex in my sed to express beginning and end of line using `^` and `$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the search expression is a regex, the replacement text isn’t:

```
sed -i -e "s/'}$/\"}/g"
```

This matches `'}` at the end of a line, and replaces it with `"}`.

Comment: how to match beginning of line?

Comment: @caduceus as hinted in the question, `^`.